# problem with RTL layout in react native project only when i release apk

Tags: react-native

i am building an app that need to support only rtl layout no matter what is the phone language.

my problem is when i am in debug mode its work just fine and show the layout rtl as i wanted regardless the phone language  but after i release the app it show the the layout direction as the phone language.
can anyone tell me what it may be ?

i tried the following solution:

add this line in the constructor of the main page

I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
        I18nManager.forceRTL(true);

also add this line in android manifest:
android:supportsRtl="true"

both in activity tag and also in application tag

manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"


  android:supportsRtl="true"
>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
  >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

constructor in App.js

constructor(){

```
    super();
    I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
}
```

this is the good result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6LUJ.jpg

this one is not what i want
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/42E4L.jpg

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add these three lines in your MainActivity.java

```
 + import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // FORCE RTL
       + I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
       + sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
        ....
    }
```